# Findstr batch file in finding listener down servers

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I'm trying to create a batch file to filter out servers which has RDP/ICA listener down from a list of servers in a notepad file, I created this script with the below syntax, but for some reasons it won't work as expected, can some one help me fix the situation?

I've a list of servers in computer.txt file and I'm trying to find the one's which are down and if errorlevel is 0, meaning the string down is found, I want the server name to be printed in listenerdown.txt , but for some reasons, if I execute the batch file, all the servers in computer.txt gets written to listenerdown.txt file

below is the batch file

```
for /f %%i in (computer.txt) do(
qwinsta /server:%%i | findstr/i down >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% neq 1
echo %%i >>Listenerdown.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `echo` onto the same line as the `if` statement or else use parentheses to establish scope and %ErrorLevel% will always be 0 because the variable does not get set in a loop without delayed expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (computer.txt) do(
    qwinsta /server:%%i | findstr /i down >nul 2>&1
    if !errorlevel! neq 1 echo %%i>>Listenerdown.txt
)
endlocal
```

or

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (computer.txt) do(
    qwinsta /server:%%i | findstr /i down >nul 2>&1
    if !errorlevel! neq 1 (
        echo %%i>>Listenerdown.txt
    )
)
endlocal
```

Cmd.exe parses batch files line by line and unless you tell it that the scope of the command continues onto the next line it will think the command is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, and `!errorlevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in (computer.txt) do (
qwinsta /server:%%i | findstr/i down >nul 2>&1
if !errorlevel! neq 1 echo %%i >>Listenerdown.txt
)
```

otherwise the value of errorlevel would be expanded only once, before entering the loop, and would not have the correct value. You also have to make sure that `echo` is in the same row as the `if`.